# Javascript Functionalized Exception Handling - keep getting uncaught type error - how to handle it?

Tags: javascript, exception

I don't think what I'm trying to do here is unreasonable within a web browser. How would you go about catching the error that always returns?

```html
function tryCatch(try_this, str_default_value){
    try {
        var test_val = try_this;
        return test_val;
    } 
    catch (error) {
        return str_default_value;
    }
}

tryCatch(digitalData.category.blah, 'default value');
```

I've seen if else logic checks beforehand but trying to avoid adding if else statements on the parent ex) if digitalData !== undefined, if digitalData.category !== undefined etc.

this is the output that I wish to have error handling for:

VM27088:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blah' of undefined

any idea?

Comment: FWIW, if you are looking specifically for a solution to accessing properties that may not exists, you can use optional chaining: `digitalData?.category.blah`.

Comment: Re @FelixKling's point, in your case you'd want `digitalData.category?.blah` or `digitalData?.category?.blah` because the issue you're having is that `digitalData.category` is `undefined`. (Note that optional chaining is quite a new JavaScript feature.)

Comment: As already said, use `digitalData?.category?.blah ?? 'default value'`.

Comment: The optional chaining fits my case perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the error is occurring *before* your call to `tryCatch`. This code:

```
tryCatch(digitalData.category.blah, 'default value');
```

does these things in order:

1. Get the value of `digitalData`
2. Get the value of the `category` property from the result of #1
3. Get the value of the `blah` property from the result of #2
4. Get the value of `'default value'`
5. Get the value of `tryCatch`
6. Call the value from #5 with the values from #3 and #4

Your code is failing at #3, because `digitalData.category` results in the value `undefined`.

Comment: I see, I thought it would only run within the function first, not outside of it, thanks.